# Blaze-html type error inside forM_ block

Tags: haskell, persistent, blaze-html, haskell-spock

I'm just starting Haskell web development using Spock, persistent and blaze-html.

In one of the routes I have, I want to load every row in my selected tables. I do something like this:

```
  get ("/show/flight/" <//> (var :: Var Integer)) $ \f -> requireUser $ \(_, l) -> do
     fs <- runSQL $ loadFlightInfos f

     case fs of
        [] -> blaze $ template False (showResultAlertBar False "Oops, something went wrong! Please try again.")
        _  -> blaze $ template True (H.toHtml $ usersUsername l) loadFlightSeat

           where
              loadFlightSeat :: H.Html
              loadFlightSeat =
                 forM_ fs $ \fs' -> do
                    sid <- runSQL $ getSeatIdByFlight fs' c

                    case sid of
                       Nothing  -> H.div H.! A.class_ "alert alert-danger" $ "Oops, something went wrong! Please try again."
                       Just rid -> H.a H.! A.href (H.toValue $ "/flight/seat/" <> show c <> "/" <> show (fromIntegral $ (fromSqlKey . entityKey) sid)) H.! A.class_ "btn btn-theme" $ H.toHtml fs'
```

`loadFlightInfos` has type:

```
Integer -> SqlPersistM [Entity Flight]
```

and getSeatIdByFlight:

```
T.Text -> Integer -> SqlPersistM (Maybe (Entity Flight))
```

I copied `runSQL` from Spock's blog sample app, and it's something like this:

```
runSQL :: (HasSpock m, SpockConn m ~ SqlBackend) => SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO)) a -> m a
runSQL action = runQuery $ \conn -> runResourceT $ runNoLoggingT $ runSqlConn action conn
```

The type error I got:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘SqlBackend’
        with actual type ‘SpockConn Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM’
In the expression: runSQL
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
   sid <- runSQL $ getSeatIdByFlight fs' c
```

I still don't understand this type error, because I know `runSQL` is a wrapper from persistent to Spock and if I simply just want to output HTML, why can't it pass type checking?

How do I resolve this type error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I didn't run your code.*

> I know `runSQL` is a wrapper from persistent to Spock

Exactly, and there lies your issue. The type of `runSQL` is:

```
runSQL :: (HasSpock m, SpockConn m ~ SqlBackend)
       => SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO)) a -> m a
```

The result type, `(HasSpock m, SpockConn m ~ SqlBackend) => m a`, tells us that `runSQL` gives a result in the Spock monad. Therefore, `loadFlightSeat` should be a Spock monad computation as well. However, you gave it type `H.Html`, which has nothing to do with the Spock monad. The issue will probably go away if you remove the mistaken type signature of `loadFlightSeat` and adjust your usage of `loadFlightSeat` accordingly:

```
     flightSeat <- loadFlightSeat -- Returns an H.Html value in the Spock monad.
     case fs of
        [] -> blaze $ template False (showResultAlertBar False "Oops, something went wrong! Please try again.")
        _  -> blaze $ template True (H.toHtml $ usersUsername l) flightSeat
```

P.S.: The type error you got...

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘SqlBackend’
        with actual type ‘SpockConn Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM’
In the expression: runSQL
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
   sid <- runSQL $ getSeatIdByFlight fs' c
```

...is unusually weird because `H.Html` [happens to be a synonym for `MarkupM ()`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html-0.8.1.0/docs/Text-Blaze-Html.html), with `MarkupM` being a monad defined by `blaze`. As a consequence, the signature you gave to `loadFlightSeat` leads the compiler to attempt matching Spock's monad with `MarkupM`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that moving out loadFlightSeat works. Though I still have confusion on why I should move it out to Spock monad (despite it's the same kind of monad).
Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @SanShin If I understand your doubt correctly, it seems you are mixing up something being in a `do`-block of some monad  with it being in a `where` clause below a `do`-block. For the purposes of your question, it doesn't really matter where you define a value like `loadFlightSeat` (i.e. whether it is in top level, a `where` clause, a `let` expression, etc.). What specifies to which monad the value belongs to, and how you have to use, is its type.